# Django Classbased views with condition

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I created script in function based view in django and I want to convert it into classbased views with if/else condition. I done searching but I didn't found the solutions. Sorry for a basic question, Im new in django and start learning.

This is my function script that I want to convert in Classbased views.

```
def vm_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Number = request.POST.get('number')
        Date = request.POST.get('date')

        if Date == '':
            Date = None
        else:
            Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(or_date,'%Y-%m-%d')

        month = ''
        endnum = ''
        if Number != '':
            endnum = int(Number[-1])
            if endnum == 1:
                month = 'January'
            elif endnum == 2:
                month = 'Febuary'
     save = Models(CS_Number=Number, CS_Date=Date, CS_Month=month)
```

I tried to convert to classbased but return is not working.

```
class vm_create(CreateView):
    model = models
    form_class = forms
    template_name = 'cs_form.html'
    def create_new(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        endnum = ''
        if request.GET.get('Number') != '':
            endnum = int(Number[-1])
            if endnum == 1:
                return 'January'
            elif endnum == 2:
                return 'Febuary'
        return super().create_new(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I think you need to overide the post method on CreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your `model` has to be `YourObjectModel`, you should not pass there `models`. Same thing with `form_class`. It has to be `YourForm` that you should store in `forms.py`. But only if you use some django's form. Otherwise use `fields` attribute.

Another thing is that you should not get values from `GET`, when you actually use `POST`. You didn't do that in your function based view, there is no reason to do it here. Last thing, you should work with `post` method or in this case, definitely with `form_valid` as you want only change one value of Model.

views.py:

```
from your_app.models import YourObjectModel

class vm_create(CreateView):
    model = YourObjectModel
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'cs_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.

        if form.instance.CS_Number != '':
            endnum = int(form.instance.CS_Number[-1])
            if endnum == 1:
                form.instance.CS_Month = 'January'
            elif endnum == 2:
                form.instance.CS_Month = 'February'

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

It's important that to use real field names (as I believe you have i.e. `CS_Number` in your model) with `form.instance` because it actually changes the values from form POSTing and sending to database.

And your template `cs_form.html` you can simply render such form with:

```
{{ form }}
```